# How to get most viewed posts using another table in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to get my most viewed posts, and I'm using yuzo plugin for count views.. But this code doesn't work.. How can I make it work ?

```
$popular = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type'             => array( 'post' ),
'showposts'             => $instance['popular_num'],
'cat'                   => $instance['popular_cat_id'],
'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
'orderby'               => 'wpng_yuzoviews.views',
'order'                 => 'dsc',
'date_query' => array(
array(
        'after' => $instance['popular_time'],
      ),
  ),
) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query will be something like:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
   'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'posts_per_page' => 5
) );
```

By default, the ordering will be highest to lowest, thus giving you the "top" 5.